# What is the correct way to access body of a request when querying mysql database?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, express

I'm working on a demo project with a simple MySql db just to learn the ropes.

My architecture is pretty simple. Request comes down the api router to my controller. Here is the controller:

```
var sendJsonResponse = function (res, status, content) {
    res.status(status);
    res.json(content);
};

module.exports.employeeCreate= function (req, res) {   

    Employee.createEmployee(req.body, function (err, employee) {
        if(err){
            sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
        }else{
            sendJsonResponse(res, 201, employee);
        }
    });
};
```

Then body of the request is passed to my model where I query the db. Here is the model file:

```
var Employee = {

    createEmployee: function (employee, cb) {  

        var name = employee[0].first_name;
        var lastName = employee[0].last_name;   

        return db.query("insert into employees set ?", {name, lastName}, cb);
    },
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to access req.body objects properties rather than first assigning them to a variable?

Comment: Not in your case, particularly when the property names you need don't match the data coming in.

Comment: @James, I had to translate property names for this question because they are in my native language. I thought this way it would make more sense to general public here :) . The req.body object is like this => { "ad": "SomeName",  "soyad":"SomeLastName"}. When I try to acces them with employee.ad or employee.soyad it records the name and last name as null.

Comment: It looks like your data is being serialised as form data rather than JSON (which you seem to expect or as)

Comment: @James ok thx. will look into it